# Is there anyway to convert a array name into a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

As the title suggests, I wish to use the name of an array as a string.
I have tried some things but i'm not sure if it is even related to the problem i'm having.

Comment: Hi, please show some of what you tried so that everyone will be able to help you

Comment: what do you mean by 'name of an array'?

Comment: When I say name of array I mean something like "var arrayThing = x", i want it to return the string "arrayThing". As for my previous code, I think it is completely unrelated so I doubt it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const getVariableName = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0];

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const arrayName = getVariableName({arr});

console.log(arrayName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of an array explicitly like so

```
var arr = []
arr.name = "arr"
```

and refer to it later as so

```
console.log(arr.name)
```

BUT there's a problem with this- array declaration in javascript is essentially just a pointer to some location in memory. Several other variables could have the a *different* 'name' assigned to them, but all still point to the same array.

Comment: Is this the only way to get the name of a array(State it beforehand)?

Comment: See the answer by @KaomiDev, as it's better than mine. But just remember, this is not a great solution to your problem and will likely cause issues in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind if I run into problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Object.keys({myArray})[0]`.

Obs.: ES2017 is required.